# Search Results module "A critical error has occurred" when upgrading to DNN 9.2.2

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9

Having an issue with my Search Results module after an upgrade from DNN 7 -> DNN 9.2.2

Everytime I search using DNN's Xcillion (built in search) I keep getting "A critical error has occurred. Please check the Event Viewer for further details." (/Default.aspx?tabid=87&error=Object+reference+not+set+to+an+instance+of+an+object.&content=0) error on the search results page.

I have tried to re-index via deleting content in search folder i.e https://dnnsupport.dnnsoftware.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004881174-Search-Not-Showing-Expected-Results

have backed up old files from /desktopmodules/admin/searchresults and added in fresh ones incase something went wrong during installation, same with DLL files that might effect the search to no avil.

Any hints or ideas would be awesome, everything else works correctly on this instance of DNN just cant figure this error out.

Admin Log error 1:

```
Message:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

StackTrace:

InnerMessage:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

InnerStackTrace:

at DotNetNuke.Modules.SearchResults.SearchResults.get_SearchContentSources() at DotNetNuke.Modules.SearchResults.SearchResults.OnLoad(EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Admin Log error 2:

```
Message:Value cannot be null. Parameter name: type

StackTrace:

at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) at DotNetNuke.Services.Search.Internals.InternalSearchControllerImpl.SearchContentSourceCallback(CacheItemArgs cacheItem) at DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities.DataCache.GetCachedDataFromRuntimeCache(CacheItemArgs cacheItemArgs, CacheItemExpiredCallback cacheItemExpired)
```

Admin Log error 3:

````
Message:Value cannot be null. Parameter name: collection

StackTrace:

at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument argument) at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.InsertRange(Int32 index, IEnumerable`1 collection) at DotNetNuke.Web.InternalServices.SearchServiceController.GetSearchContentSources(IList`1 typesList) at DotNetNuke.Web.InternalServices.SearchServiceController.Preview(String keywords, String culture, Int32 forceWild, Int32 portal) at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] ) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken) --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.d__18`1.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.d__18`1.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.d__0.MoveNext()```
````

Answer (score 1):

Did you follow the recommended upgrade path, or did you do this in a single step?

Do you have the option to revert and try the upgrade again?

Comment: Yeah followed the recommened upgrade path, so in incremental steps.
I do have the option to revert and try again, maybe when i have more avalible time :)